# Lining up circles based on diameter

Tags: javascript, geometry

I'm trying to line up some planets (circles) so that any asteroids (also circles) in their orbit will not enter another planet's orbit.

This is how the placing of planets is done:

```js
let distance = 0;
for (let index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
    const created = new planet(this, distance);
    this.planets.push(created);

    const diameter = created.getDiameter();
    distance += diameter;
}
```

The diameter of a planet is the diameter of the asteroid with the highest radius:

```js
getDiameter() {
    const furthest = this.asteroids.reduce((previous, current) => {
        return (previous.radius > current.radius) ? previous : current;
    });
    return 1 + ceil(2 * furthest.radius);
}
```

This is the result of that placement:

[image: Result].

Sometimes the circles overlap, other times they appear a few pixels off or have large gaps between them.

The planets positions are constantly updating but for debugging I disabled updating of their angle. I don't think this code is affecting anything:

```js
setPosition() {
    const rads = radians(this.angle);
    this.position.x = (this.radius * cos(rads)) + this.star.position.x;
    this.position.y = (this.radius * sin(rads)) + this.star.position.y;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New planet should be placed at distance

```
LeftPlanetRadius + RightPlanetRadius
```

rather than `2 * LeftPlanetRadius` distance
*(note that your right small-orbit planet is too far, while planet with larger orbit will overlap with left orbit)*

So you have to modify planet creation - at first you need to get it's radius to provide proper position